# getting selected value from select list with jquery in mvc

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, select, selectedvalue

How can I get the selected value from a drop down list in mvc from jquery to the controller.

View:

```
<tr><td>Choose League: </td><td><select name="leagueSelection" id="leagueIdDrop" class="dropdownlistLeagueStyle"><option value="1">Barclays Premier League</option><option value="6">Bundesliga</option><option value="7">Seria A</option><option value="8">Ligue 1</option><option value="9">La Liga</option><option value="10">Eredivisie</option></select></td><td><input id="leagueButton" class="loginButton" value="GetTeams" type="submit" /></td></tr>
```

I need to get the selected value so I can pass through the get teams method parameter

Comment: Please state your intentions better. So the user selects a value in the list, now what happens? What do you expect to happen for the user? What existing code do you have?

Comment: I need to get the select value to the controller

Comment: Please explain how the flow on your page is. The flow of the user! You just repeat what you have stated before. The action, should it happen after a button push? Is it a form submit? Is it an AJAX call?

Comment: look at this...use a switch statement? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1435012/switch-statement-in-jquery-and-list

Comment: but how do I get the value in the controller

Answer (score 3, accepted):

based on the name attribute of your select, you will want to have a parameter named "leagueSelection" in you controller's action.  Assuming that your select is contained within a form element that posts to *controller name*/Submit.

```
public ActionResult Submit(int leagueSelection)
{
    // do what ever you want
}
```

you can also post with query string parameters

```
$.ajax({
  type: 'POST',
  url: '/controller/submit?leagueSelection=' + $('#leagueIdDrop').val()
});
```

Comment: I am not using forms thats why I am using jquery to get result....all I need to know is how to get the jquery result from my jquery to the controller

Comment: post using query strings then.

Comment: This seems really good but I am getting this as value when passing leagueSelection as string in controller = "'   $('"